Keep single-column heading together with multi-colunmn text
In MS Word, apparently, the only way to have a heading span the full page width above text in multi-column layout is to format the heading as single-column. When I do that, however, the heading is no longer kept together with the text, even though its paragraph has "Keep with next" checked.
When I show all formatting marks, I see that there is now a section break following the heading, and if I delete the section break, then the heading is merged into the multi-column layout of the following text and no longer spans the width of the page.
This seems like it should be a really common and obvious requirement, but apparently MS Word cannot handle it. Am I missing something?

Please edit the question and include screenshots of the heading before and after the changes plus when you show the paragraph marks.
